# Source File requires different compiler version

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle

I am using solidity version "**pragma solidity ^0.4.20;**". When I checked JSON files of contract, compiler version shows :

```
"compiler": {
    "name": "solc",
    "version": "0.4.21+commit.dfe3193c.Emscripten.clang"
  }
```

Still I am getting error :

> Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is
>   0.5.0+commit.1d4f565a.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version

Command '**truffle version**' gives :

```
 Truffle v4.1.5 (core: 4.1.5)
 Solidity v0.4.21 (solc-js)
```

Comment: What are you doing specifically that triggers that error? Trying to run the Solc binaries?

Comment: I was deploying contract to privatenet. The contract was running fine and suddenly this error occurred. When I change pragma solidity ^0.4.20;  to  pragma solidity 0.5.0; error disappears.  Even there is error, I am able to deploy contracts.

Comment: The error implies the installed Solidity compiler is version which is trying to compile your solidity code is v0.5.0. So the question I am asking is how are you triggering the compilation? Clearly solc-js is not being used since it appears to have the right version.

Comment: Like @ShawnTabrizi pointed out, we need to know how the compilation is triggered. Often this will happen because people have different truffle versions installed globally vs locally for the project. If you're compiling with the locally installed truffle, it may be a newer version that has 0.5.0, but not new enough that it has BYOC (bring your own compiler). Then when you do `truffle version`, it uses the global one which is the right version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

During solidity (solc) 0.5 releases the different frameworks like solc, truffle, web3, openzeppelin had a timeframe where some had a 0.5 compatible version released and some didn't. I think you could have changed specified the solc version like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53976093/828184) (didn't try that) but meanwhile all of the mentioned fully support 0.5 (openzeppelin since 2 days ago at time of writing).

Consider doing the following

```
npm outdated
npm install [my-outdated-package] #repeat for all outdated packages
rm -R -f build #cleanup step (might not be necessary)
rm -R -f node_modules #cleanup step (might not be necessary)
npm install
truffle compile #(will still fail)
```

Check with `truffle version` in a terminal window at some other place (not project dir) if it matches the current release [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases) otherwise do this:

```
npm uninstall -g truffle
npm install truffle
```

Usually you should avoid installing global packages but e.g. BlockCatIO/solidity-flattener requires that solc is installed globally because of certain features (installation described [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/installing-solidity.html#binary-packages)). Remember to upgrade that one too.

When you then run truffle-compile you should still see errors because they changed the syntax of pragma (found that [here](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/5519#issuecomment-442109936)).

So change:

```
#old
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

#new
pragma solidity >=0.4.20;
```

I also recommend upgrading ganache-cli (I had problems running the tests with old version):

```
npm install -g ganache-cli
```

You might then still see compile errors but that's what makes v0.5 great because they made some improvements you should troubleshoot one-by-one

Here the [Breaking Changes in Solidity 0.5.0](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html)

Doing this I got it compiling again :)

Answer (score 18):

Thanks, I was using visualstudio editor and enabled an extension for solidity where compiler version was upgraded.  By [**specifying**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JuanBlanco.solidity) the version of compiler in Editor resolved the issue for me.

Comment: What setting did you change? What value did you give it? How did you get to that setting?

Comment: @PhilipRego You probably figured it out, however, for anyone using a Mac: CTRL + Click anywhere within the contract file using your VS editor and select "Change Compiler Version", it will then display a list of compiler versions for your selection beginning with the latest. For windows you may need to right click.

Comment: With Windows, WSL (Ubuntu) and VS Code I did just that: CTRL+right click in the editor, then `Solidity: Change workspace compiler version (Remote)`, selected a version that was suggested for the particular project and it worked.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. In case you are working on an older project and you can't switch the version, you will have to use a different compiler version :)

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using `solc-select` (https://github.com/crytic/solc-select), it will allow switching easily between solc versions.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be well maintained or at least not for macOS https://github.com/crytic/solc-select/issues/26

Comment: Problem seems to be resolved with macOS, at least I can use it

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and by doing following, my error disappeared.

The syntax change in pragma is giving error.
just Change `pragma solidity ^0.4.20;` to `pragma solidity >=0.4.20;`.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me is the following:

1. Type `ctrl+SHIFT+p`
2. Select `solidity:Change Global compiler version (Remote)`
3. Select your desired solidity version
4. Additionally, I needed to change in the setting of `solidity extension` by Juan Blanco. Click on the settings icon and go to `extension settings`
5. Set Solidity default compiler option to `remote`
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

Try format of compiler at first line of Contract .sol :-
 pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0

It worked for me. Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and by doing following, my error disappeared.

The syntax change in pragma is giving error. just Change pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;.

Post doing this you will get an warning

Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: " to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.

Just add it above pragma line.

// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

Comment: This will work if the source code was is compatible with the new solc version. If it is not compatible you will have to fix all the issues.

Answer (score 1):

## Fix

Change the source of the compiler for the extension:

- Open the command palette `ctrl+p`
- Type > followed by `Change the default workspace`
- Select remote and then `Change Global compiler version (Remote)` to your version, or an option that suits your project the best.
- You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/juanfranblanco/vscode-solidity#using-a-different-version-of-the-solidity-compiler)
- Keep the grind

#### Reference

https://cesarvarela.com/blog/fix-source-file-requires-different-compiler-version.

Answer (score 1):

So this is how you solve this compiler version problem.(Worked for me)

Right click the pragma solidity statement, and select the following option:

Solidity: Change workspace compiler version (Remote)

Then, all you have to do is select the Solidity compiler you want.

Answer (score 0):

Run npm install solc
go to package.json
check the version of solc
after go to truffle.config.json
replace he version make sure its the same as in package.json
change it on sol ils too

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar error and I updated my file with the following

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
```

Consider making these changes and your project will update

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings of VS Code. Choose default compiler => remote

choose and copy paste the version you want to support https://etherscan.io/solcversions

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **Juan Blanco's** Solidity extension for **VS Code**, besides the compiler version in the `truffle-config.js` you will also have to change the compiler version of the extension itself. To do that:

1. Open **VS Code** command palette by pressing **Ctrl+Shift+P**
2. Type `Solidity: Change global compiler version (Remote)` then press enter
3. This will open another menu from which you can select the desired version

**NOTE:** Only changing the extension's compiler version will actually allow you to compile your contract causing some warning. Nevertheless, it is important to also change the compiler version in the `truffle-config.js` file, because when compiling outside of your VS Code instance, the version specified that file will be used. You can verify that by running `truffle compile --compiler` in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this :

```
    compilers: {
solc: {
  version: "^0.4.20"
}
}
```

Where "^0.4.20" is the version of the compiler you want to use.

So your truffle config file should look like this :

```
   module.exports = {
     networks: {
       development: {
         host: "127.0.0.1",
         port: 7545,
         network_id: "*" // Match any network id
       }
   },
    compilers: {
      solc: {
        version: "^0.4.20"
         }
       }
     };
```

And the problem will be solved :)

Don't forget to check the documentation :
https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration/#compiler-configuration