# How to upgrade solidity compiler solc to version 0.5.x?

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am using solidity 0.4.24. The latest version has been updated. How to upgrade my solidity version? Is there any commands for it?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your valuable comments. I have done it by uninstalling and reinstalling truffle.

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17551/how-to-upgrade-solidity-compiler-in-truffle/62923#62923) if you're using Truffle.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the new compiler.

- If you are using Remix, choose the new one in the “Run” tab, drop up “compiler” menu.
- If you are using Node, npm install -g solc@latest (at the moment it is 0.5.3).
- If you are using truffle, upgrade to truffle 5.

You will be possibly required to upgrade/correct your code too: simply follow the compiler errors and warning messages and upgrade your code accordingly to the now updated 0.5.3 documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from upgrading the compiler, you will most likely need to migrate your contracts. A useful guide for migrating is https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/050-breaking-changes.html.

Answer (score 1):

Your question tagging implies that you are compiling via Truffle.

If so, then simply upgrade your Truffle version from 4.x to 5.x.

If installed globally, then just run `npm update -g truffle`.

If installed locally, then in `package.json`, change this:

```
"truffle": "4.1.14" // I am guessing it's 4.1.14 because your solc version is 0.4.24
```

To this:

```
"truffle": "5.0.2" // The latest version at this point in time
```