# Solidity Compiler won't upgrade

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle, ganache

I updated to the latest version of `Truffle` using:

```
npm uninstall -g truffle
```

followed by:

```
npm install -g truffle
```

I verified this succeeded by doing:

```
truffle --version
```

and got this:

[image]

You can clearly see that I'm on version `5.0.3`

I read that updating `Truffle` would pretty much also automatically update the `Solidity` compiler.

but when I do:

```
solc --version
```

I get this:

[image]

So its still on version `0.4.24`

So I did again.
And again.
And its not working.

I've done it globally - and I've done it locally, meaning in my specific project's Directory.

Nothing works.

I tried doing it directly, by uninstalling Solidity - like this:

```
npm uninstall solc -g
```

-then reinstalling it using:

```
npm install solc -g
```

I've done pretty much everything I can think of, but its still telling me that I'm on version `0.4.24`.

What's going on? What am I missing here?

========================================================

UPDATE:

I added the following to my `truffle.js` file:

```
compilers: {
    solc: {
        version: "0.5.0"  // ex:  "0.4.20". (Default: Truffle's installed solc)
    }
}
```

That's obviously supposed to force the use of that particular version of the compiler.

I recompiled and redeployed to `ropsten` - and that all worked.

So at this point, I'm assuming that the project is being compiled using v 0.5.0 of Solidity - but *is* it?

Here's my big question right now: how can I tell - like during run time, what compiler version is actually being used on my project at any given time?
Cause at this point, I'm still getting errors in my DApp - the HTML & JS files that are querying the contract I deployed - that seem to do with the compiler+solidity versions - which was the reason I updated `truffle` to version 5 in the first place, to solve these issued. (But that's another matter. One thing at a time.)

===========================================================================

UPDATE#2

This shows everything:

[image]

-I'm installing solc v. 0.5.3 *directly into* my project's folder (I've already done the Global install several times.)

-I get 2 warnings - I don't know what they mean - but it says it installed `14 packages from 5 contributors`, which sounds pretty good.

-but then when I do `solc version`, it tells me I'm on version `0.4.24`

I've literally spent all day trying to resolve this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92098/discussion-on-question-by-sirab33-solidity-compiler-wont-upgrade).

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17551/how-to-upgrade-solidity-compiler-in-truffle

Answer (score 3):

On your project root directory, there's a file named "truffle-config.js"

Inside this file, you can find a solc config, and uncomment version line, and then put your prefer version. (ex: 0.5.7)

```
compilers: {
    solc: {
       version: "0.5.7",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
      // settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
      //  optimizer: {
      //    enabled: false,
      //    runs: 200
      //  },
      //  evmVersion: "byzantium"
      // }
    }
  }
```

After this, just compile and truffle will download that version of solc automatically.

```
$ truffle compile
```

Boom!

Comment: But with your solution,  it downloads the solc version everytime you compile! Ideally it should download once and save it locally. If it is found locally then compile otherwise donwload it.