# Truffle compiler version not changing

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, contract-debugging, truffle-migration

truffle.js:

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
var mnemonic = "";

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    testnet: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, ""),
      network_id: 97,
      confirmations: 10,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      skipDryRun: true
    },
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
    rinkeby: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: 4,
      gasPrice: "20000000000", // 20 gwei
    },
    live: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "1", // Only mainnet
      gasPrice: "10000000000", // 10 gwei
      gas: "5000000", // 0.02 eth at 4 gwei price
    },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "^0.8.4",
    },
  },
 }
};
```

But I keep getting the error: `Error: Truffle is currently using solc 0.5.16, but one or more of your contracts specify "pragma solidity >=0.8.4"`.

I have even tried the solutions in [How to upgrade solidity compiler in truffle](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17551/how-to-upgrade-solidity-compiler-in-truffle/47244), but none helped.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a wrongly placed `}`. I suggest to format the file then it should be obvious that compiler is in the wrong section.

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    live: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "1", // Only mainnet
      gasPrice: "10000000000", // 10 gwei
      gas: "5000000", // 0.02 eth at 4 gwei price
    }, /////// <------ MISSING } //////
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "^0.8.4",
    },
  },
 }     /////// <------ HERE IS THE MISSING } ///////
};
```

It should be like this

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    live: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "1", // Only mainnet
      gasPrice: "10000000000", // 10 gwei
      gas: "5000000", // 0.02 eth at 4 gwei price
    },
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "^0.8.4",
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: network and compilers should be sibling keys, so there needs to be another closing brace `}` above the compilers key to close out the network entry.