# Truffle compiler stuck at 0.4.17

Tags: truffle, solc

Coming from here: [How do I specify a different Solidity version in a Truffle contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15749/how-do-i-specify-a-different-solidity-version-in-a-truffle-contract)
I still have the same issue, except that even after trying all of the suggested solutions, and even having the `truffle-config.js` working before by specifying the right version there, my new project doesn't seem to take the version entered in consideration.
I'm working with:

```
Truffle v5.1.15 (core: 5.1.15)
Solidity - 0.6.4 (solc-js)
Node v12.16.1
Web3.js v1.2.1
```

And this is my compiler code:

```
compilers: {
    solc: {
        version: "0.6.4"
    },
}
```

Whenever I start a new .sol file with `pragma solidity ^0.6.4`, `pragma` is highlighted with the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.4.17+commit.bdeb9e52.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity ^0.6.4;
^---------------------^
```

So my IDE still believes my compiler is going to be 0.4.17...
If I keep writing, I keep getting errors due to deprecated error highlighting (`constructor` and `emit` events not working, `now` is okay...).

Does anyone know what I might have missed?

Comment: Your IDE is wrong. Are you using atom? Which extension/plugin are you using? Sometimes reinstalling the extension will fix that message.

Comment: Any chance you have Truffle 4.x globally-installed on your machine (i.e., via `npm install -g truffle`)?

Comment: I'm using VSCode, I've already tried `npm uninstall -g truffle` followed by `npm install -g truffle`, I've already tried disabling and reenabling the `solidity` extension by Juan Blanco, but everything is still the same... So I think I have all the latest versions of everything :/

Comment: Type `npm ls truffle` from some path outside of your project folder.

Comment: I just uninstalled it, so I get empty right now... And even that didn't fix it and I'm still stuck with 0.4.17...
Something more weird is I have another project from 5 months ago which used to working fine, then had the same problem about a month ago, and then got it back to be working again. All I did was uninstalling npm and installing nvm before instead.
But the point is the older project is working, so I believe this to be a local problem...

Comment: @Thanh-QuyNguyen I use VS Code with Juan extension and I've no issues. Check if there's an old version of solc installed globally `npm ls -g --depth=0`, uninstall it if that's the case. Also look at the extension settings it allows to override the version you want.

Comment: @Ismael I have nothing, but just in case I uninstalled solc and reinstalled it, and it still doesn't work :/

Comment: @Thanh-QuyNguyen It seems the extension uses the version of solc installed in your project. If you run `npm install solc@0.6.4` in your project it will use that version.

Comment: @Ismael That solved it! Thanks!